# Connecting "with" or "to"

Tags: prepositions, word-usage

I read the answers to similar questions, but I need to be sure.

I chose the sentence: "Connecting solutions with people" on my business card and want to be sure it's not suppose to be "Connecting solutions to people".

I wanted to emphasis that the solutions often comes from looking at peoples' behavior so the people are who supply the solutions (even if unaware of it), and sometimes the solutions are coming from the technology itself.

Hope I managed to explain myself.

Thanks,
Iris

Comment: Fie on't, o fie.

Comment: As RegDwigнt says, the slogan looks a bit awkward. I'd suggest writing *Providing solutions to people* because ideally you don't **connect** solutions, you **provide** them!

Comment: Yes, you can *provide* or *offer* or *find*, but the thing is, every other business card in the world says just that. Every other company claims it miraculously finds solutions people are unaware of and brings them to the unaware people. It's trite. So *connect* actually gets points for originality. Except, as I said, it sounds horrible. Torture chambers is where you connect things and apply solutions to people. And it's way too vague to top it off. What "solutions"? What "people"? Will you fix my kitchen sink? Will you fly Putin to Jupiter? Do you have experience working with giraffes?

Comment: There are better options to that then. I'd say 'Discover solutions', @RegDwigнt

Comment: @RegDwigнt - the OP didn't ask for an opinion on the suitability or money-making aspects of the slogan. That would make the question a matter of opinion and so off-topic.  The question is about grammar and I think we should discourage non-relevant discussions in comments. Your comment has actually sparked such a discussion. By the way, as you say, slogans don't have to be complete sentences so that is not really relevant either.

Answer (score 1):

As @Maulik V says, you **provide** solutions to people.

Alternately, if you wanted to use **connect**, I think a clever way to do it would be **Connecting people with solutions** , though that could be problematic as well.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments and the graphical depictions. I will take them into consideration. Indeed, I am looking more for a grammar advice than a content one. Slogan are a unique way of expression and not always need to be logical (a whole theory that I won't get into). So...You all agreed that "Connecting Solutions with People" is horrible...what about "Bridging" and some combination with "Solutions" and "People" - 2 words I have to use, they are the keywords for my purpose.... Thanks!

Comment: How about **pairing people with solutions**

Comment: "Pairing" doesn't sound good to me. How is it different from "Connecting" in terms of grammar?

Answer (score 0):

Back to the question at hand...

The preposition "with" in "Connecting solutions with people" seems to imply that the action of making the connection is being done with people, that is, done with or by the assistance of people. The "to" of Connecting solutions to people" seems to get at the intent of the card, helping people find the solutions they're looking for.